# value of type string has no member stringbyappendingpathcomponent

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3, swift3.2

[image]

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

```
var window: UIWindow?
lazy var  coreDataStack = CoreDataStack()

func getSavePathsForListWithName(_ name: String) -> String {
    let pathsArray = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(FileManager.SearchPathDirectory.documentDirectory, FileManager.SearchPathDomainMask.userDomainMask, true)
    let documentDirectory = pathsArray[0] 
    return documentDirectory.stringByAppendingPathComponent(name)}// Getting error in this line
```

I'm converting swift 1.2 to swift 3.2 but getting this error. i have replaced stringByAppendingPathComponent with URLByAppendingPathCompont but not working.

can some one please help me i'm facing this problem, it will be great help me, thanks in advance.

`

Comment: casting to NSString is not working and suggesting appendingPathComponent after that it is giving 164 errors

Comment: That method is not available in Swift. Perhaps you can use .appending(String) method. But you may have to put "/" at the beginning of the string

Comment: `return documentDirectory+name` or `return "\(documentDirectory)\(name)`